# find and exec: why does this command not work?

Tags: find, echo, cygwin

I don't get why echo prints empty line (latest cygwin version):

```
~/tmp >find mydor/ -name "*php"
mydor/es/c/packags.php
mydor/etns/inx.php
mydor/pacepors.php
mydor/XAE.php

~/tmp >find mydor/ -name "*php" -exec echo {} \;
~/tmp >find mydor/ -name "*php" -exec echo "{}" \;
~/tmp >find mydor/ -name "*php" -exec echo '{}' \;

~/tmp >

~/tmp >find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
Packaged by Cygwin (4.5.11-1)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

Comment: Works for me. You will have to give us details about `find` and `echo`, for example from which packages they come and what are their versions.

Comment: Are you running it from the Cygwin terminal? (The installer puts an icon on your desktop, pointing to “C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -” or similar.)

Comment: Running from tty with `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe` and base path `C:\cygwin\bin`. More strange: this works: `find mydor/ -name "*php" -exec cat {} \;`

Comment: What `echo` command is `find` calling? What does `bash -c 'type -a echo'` tell you? The first non-builtin one would be the one it calls.

Comment: Probably I didn't reproduced the circumstances exactly, I had to specify the path to the executables, otherwise Windows' own `find` was executed. But as soon as I specified the path, it worked.

Comment: I think I'm getting close to the solution, which is close to @manatwork's idea: `find mydor/ -name "*php" -exec sh -c "echo {}" \;` works.

Comment: Actually the sub-shell was mentioned by @StephaneChazelas. I would try `./find mydor/ -name "*php" -exec ./echo {} \;`. (Supposing `PWD` is C:\cygwin\bin.)

Comment: There's something wrong with `echo`: if I try `~/tmp> /usr/bin/echo "test"` I get nothing.

Comment: Are you typing this at a bash prompt or at a cmd prompt?

Comment: I'm typing this at a cygwin mintty bash prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the answer. Here's how I made it work (and there's a solution to exec 2 process in a row only if the first one succeded, which I didn't found with google):

```
find ./ -name "*php" -exec sh -c "sed 's/ \+ /\t/g' \"{}\" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile \"{}\"" \;
```

Comment: DO NOT embed the `{}` in the `sh` code! See `sed -i` (with GNU `sed` but you're already using a GNUism with `\+`) for in-place editing.